# Maven build fails through Eclipse with Java 7

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, java-8, java-7

I've set up a new Maven project webapp with Eclipse 2022-06 (4.24.0) which has Maven 3.8.4 embedded. According to the [Maven release notes info](https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html) requires Java 1.7.

If I do a package with Java 1.7, the build fails with an error that indicates that need Java 1.8:

```
Apache Maven 3.8.4 (9b656c72d54e5bacbed989b64718c159fe39b537)
Maven home: D:\Proyectos\java\hello-world\eclipse\workspace\hello-world\EMBEDDED
Java version: 1.7.0_79, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre
Default locale: es_ES, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "windows 8.1", version: "6.3", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
---------------------------------------------------
constituent[0]: file:/D:/Proyectos/java/hello-world/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/
constituent[1]: file:/D:/Proyectos/java/hello-world/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-core-3.8.4.jar
constituent[2]: file:/D:/Proyectos/java/hello-world/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-model-3.8.4.jar
constituent[3]: file:/D:/Proyectos/java/hello-world/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-settings-3.8.4.jar
constituent[4]: file:/D:/Proyectos/java/hello-world/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-settings-builder-3.8.4.jar
constituent[5]: file:/D:/Proyectos/java/hello-world/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-builder-support-3.8.4.jar
constituent[6]: file:/D:/Proyectos/java/hello-world/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-repository-metadata-3.8.4.jar
constituent[7]: file:/D:/Proyectos/java/hello-world/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-artifact-3.8.4.jar
constituent[8]: file:/D:/Proyectos/java/hello-world/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-plugin-api-3.8.4.jar
constituent[9]: file:/D:/Proyectos/java/hello-world/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-model-builder-3.8.4.jar
constituent[10]: file:/D:/Proyectos/java/hello-world/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-resolver-provider-3.8.4.jar
constituent[11]: file:/D:/Proyectos/java/hello-world/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-resolver-api-1.6.3.jar
constituent[12]: file:/D:/Proyectos/java/hello-world/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-resolver-spi-1.6.3.jar
constituent[13]: file:/D:/Proyectos/java/hello-world/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-resolver-util-1.6.3.jar
constituent[14]: file:/D:/Proyectos/java/hello-world/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-shared-utils-3.3.4.jar
constituent[15]: file:/D:/Proyectos/java/hello-world/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/commons-io-2.6.jar
constituent[16]: file:/D:/Proyectos/java/hello-world/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.3.5.jar
constituent[17]: file:/D:/Proyectos/java/hello-world/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/guice-4.2.2-no_aop.jar
constituent[18]: file:/D:/Proyectos/java/hello-world/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/plexus-utils-3.3.0.jar
constituent[19]: file:/D:/Proyectos/java/hello-world/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/plexus-interpolation-1.26.jar
constituent[20]: file:/D:/Proyectos/java/hello-world/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/plexus-component-annotations-2.1.0.jar
constituent[21]: file:/D:/Proyectos/java/hello-world/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar
constituent[22]: file:/D:/Proyectos/java/hello-world/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-embedder-3.8.4.jar
constituent[23]: file:/D:/Proyectos/java/hello-world/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
constituent[24]: file:/D:/Proyectos/java/hello-world/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/plexus-sec-dispatcher-2.0.jar
constituent[25]: file:/D:/Proyectos/java/hello-world/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/plexus-cipher-2.0.jar
constituent[26]: file:/D:/Proyectos/java/hello-world/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/commons-cli-1.4.jar
constituent[27]: file:/D:/Proyectos/java/hello-world/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-compat-3.8.4.jar
constituent[28]: file:/D:/Proyectos/java/hello-world/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/wagon-provider-api-3.4.3.jar
constituent[29]: file:/D:/Proyectos/java/hello-world/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/org.eclipse.sisu.plexus-0.3.5.jar
constituent[30]: file:/D:/Proyectos/java/hello-world/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/aether-connector-okhttp-0.17.8.jar
constituent[31]: file:/D:/Proyectos/java/hello-world/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/okhttp-3.14.1.jar
constituent[32]: file:/D:/Proyectos/java/hello-world/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/okio-1.17.3.jar
constituent[33]: file:/D:/Proyectos/java/hello-world/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-resolver-impl-1.6.3.jar
constituent[34]: file:/D:/Proyectos/java/hello-world/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-resolver-connector-basic-1.6.3.jar
constituent[35]: file:/D:/Proyectos/java/hello-world/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-resolver-transport-wagon-1.6.3.jar
constituent[36]: file:/D:/Proyectos/java/hello-world/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/wagon-file-3.4.3.jar
constituent[37]: file:/D:/Proyectos/java/hello-world/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/jansi-2.4.0.jar
constituent[38]: file:/D:/Proyectos/java/hello-world/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple_1.18.1.20211008-0657/
constituent[39]: file:/D:/Proyectos/java/hello-world/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple_1.18.1.20211008-0657/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.30.jar
constituent[40]: file:/D:/Proyectos/java/hello-world/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/9/0/.cp/
constituent[41]: file:/D:/Proyectos/java/hello-world/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/879/0/.cp/
constituent[42]: file:/D:/Proyectos/java/hello-world/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/30/0/.cp/
---------------------------------------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:425)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.<clinit>(Errors.java:105)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.<init>(InternalInjectorCreator.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:87)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:69)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.addPlexusInjector(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:481)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.<init>(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:206)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.container(MavenCli.java:651)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:196)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
```

But, if I change the JRE compiler to 1.8, the build is success:
[image]

Furthermore, if I configure a new maven runtime with Maven 3.6.2, external of eclipse, I can compile with Java 1.7 and Java 1.8.

This is my pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>hello-world</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>hello-world Maven Webapp</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>hello-world</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.2</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

So, it's a eclipse bug? or isn´t really compatible Maven 3.8.4 with Java 7? Or I missing any extra config?

Thank you!

Comment: Without doing a real analysis, you should consider Java 11 or 17, as both 1.7 or 1.8 are End-of-Life.

Comment: Actually, the real project is an enterprise project that runs on a Tomcat 7 with Java 7 and that is compiled with Java 8 and what I want is to unify the compiler and the execution so that they are with the same version of Java, in this case with Java 7. This is just an example to reproduce the problem...

Comment: The error comes from a class from Google Guava. That's used by Maven - `org.apache.maven:maven-core` has a dependency on `com.google.inject:guice` which has a dependency on `com.google.guava:guava`.  The Guava used by `maven-core` 3.8.4 and 3.8.6 is 25.1-android, which is built to be compatible with Java 7. My guess is that Eclipse comes with a newer version of Guava which somehow overrides the version used by Maven. What happens if you build on the command line with Maven 3.8.4?

Comment: If the Maven version that is included in Eclipse does not work for you, you can install a Maven on your system and configure it in the preferences _Maven > Installations_. In the Maven run configuration you can choose in the _Main_ tab at the bottom whether to use the _EMBEDDED_ one or the one you installed. Does running Maven of the same version as the embedded one make a difference? I wouldn't assume so, but it's up to you to find that out.

Comment: Thanks both. @rob-spoor You are right. I saw in the plugins folder of eclipse a plugin named `com.google.guava_30.1.0.v20210127-2300.jar`. Opening this jar in `\META-INF\maven\org.eclipse.orbit.bundles\com.google.guava\pom.xml` there are a dependency to `com.google.guava` with version `30.1-jre` and in https://github.com/google/guava says `The JRE flavor requires JDK 1.8 or higher`, so the version should be `31.1-android`. If you post as and answer, I´ll mark as accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes from a class from Google Guava. That's used by Maven - org.apache.maven:maven-core has a dependency on com.google.inject:guice which has a dependency on com.google.guava:guava. The Guava used by maven-core 3.8.4 and 3.8.6 is 25.1-android, which is built to be compatible with Java 7. My guess is that Eclipse comes with a newer version of Guava which somehow overrides the version used by Maven.